# Extjs 4.1 - Disable paste event for textfields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, textfield

I already verified there are no paste events for textfield in extjs 4.1. But i donot want that user should be able to paste into this textfield. What other options are available that user is not allowed to paste any value in the textfield. Please note that the textfield allows only numeric values, no chars/special chars or alphabets. Below is the code snippet that i have as of now.

```
{
                                  xtype:"textfield",    
                                  fieldLabel: 'Debit Account',
                                  name:'debitAccount',
                                  id : 'debitacct',
                                  enableKeyEvents:true,
                                  maskRe: /[0-9]/,
                                  allowBlank: false,
                                  allowNegative: false,
                                  maxLength: 9,
                                  enforceMaxLength:true,
                                  listeners : {
                                    specialkey : function(field, e) {
                                    filterBackspaceKey(e);
                                    }
                                    }
                             }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @dbrin My bad, Thank you ! I just accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After i got to see the link @Sencha, the solution was easy. Code below.

```
{
                                  xtype:"textfield",    
                                  fieldLabel: 'Debit Account',
                                  name:'debitAccount',
                                  id : 'debitacct',
                                  enableKeyEvents:true,
                                  maskRe: /[0-9]/,
                                  allowBlank: false,
                                  allowNegative: false,
                                  maxLength: 9,
                                  enforceMaxLength:true,
                                  listeners : {
                                    specialkey : function(field, e) {
                                    filterBackspaceKey(e);
                                    },
                                    paste: {
                                        element: 'inputEl',
                                        fn: function(event, inputEl) {
                                        if(event.type == "paste"){
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        return false;
                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    }
                             }
```

Refer link from Sencha : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175253-Paste-event

Answer (score 1):

- On any click and keydown do this:

  - Check if old value equals to new value (change event)
  - Save new value to old value
  - If content has changed, you can diff the values and if changed part was more then one character, content has been pasted -> revert to old value

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You @Lex Podgorny for the response. After googling a little bit i did find a paste event, ref http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175253-Paste-event

Comment: @SKS Shouldn't the answer using the paste event be the correct one then?

Comment: @carcel, that's right. Paste event is the best option available.

Answer (score 0):

try after change your listeners to below

```
listeners : {
                change : function(field, newValue,oldValue) {
                    var validation=/^\d+$/;
                    if(!validation.test(newValue) && newValue!='' ) {
                        field.setValue(oldValue);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I was looking for a paste event and not change. Anyways thank you for the code. Please do check my piece of code too as solution.